# Magento 2 / Add Buy Now button in Recently Viewed Products

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to add "Buy Now" button in Recently Viewed Products widget, the widget is made with knockout js.

The file involved in the widget is: **/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html**

I appreciate any help.

Comment: how you added recently viewed product ? using admin widget ?